# Question of ball falling down.Difficulty in understanding the formula

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, free-fall, integrals-of-motion, equations-of-motion

[image]

A ball is thrown upward from the top of a tower 40m high. u = 10m/s.Find time for it reach AD.
g = $10m/s^2$.

Taking upwards direction as +ve and downward as -ve.

u = +10m/s.$g=-10m/s^2$.s=-40.

$-40 = 10t - 5t^2$ . This is the equation in my book.
Since the formula that we have is of displacement of the body.
I am getting confused in this formula actually.

Why is the time that we have found no from A-D directly but from A-B and then C -D.

Isn’t displacement = distance here ?[image]

Comment: You can do it in few ways. And about origin, yo can place it where you like more. I would see it better at ground, or at the top of the tower. But once you place vectors correctly, you can choose what makes your task easier.

Comment: Ok.The right is to make coordinate right

Comment: Have I made velocity correct and acceleration correct in coordinate@Alchimista

Comment: [![enter image description here][1]][1]; is there any image you wanted to insert as it is not clear what are A, B, C and D?

Comment: @Notwen  check now.Is it good

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the time that we have found no from A-D directly but from A-B and then C -D.

Because when you specify u = 40 it means that initially it will travel some distance upwards due to initial velocity and then only go to D along the path B->C->D(due to gravity).

> Isn’t displacement = distance here ?

No the direction of velocity changes.